# How do you build a database-centric site in WP?

Tags: database

The best way to explain this might be to relate my site to a comparison shopping site, as I have around seven tables with 500k+ records each. The content on my site is a comparison of items, and involves variable MySQL queries to create the "content". I imagine there is a way to build database intensive websites on WP, but I have not been able to find the answer thus far.

Comment: I think he means that he have a full db schema and he wants hos data centric app to respect relations...He wishes for an ORM...

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by "database intensive websites on WP". Do you want to keep your existing database tables and custom SQL queries and use them *within* a WordPress website? Or do you want to import your data into WordPress and use as much of the builtin database functionality as possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not complicated to connect to custom tables in WP context and query them, using native `wpdb` class.

However "not complicated" is about all there it. WP API functions are primarily aimed at querying its own data structures. While `wpdb` does have some helpers, they are simplistic and not meant for more elaborate custom queries.

Another issue is that by implementation `wpdb` drags all of query results into memory immediately. This is Bad Idea for any queries that return large amounts of data. WordPress backup plugins (which are query-intensive by definition) typically have to implement their querying from scratch, otherwise they just crash on large sites.

In a nutshell WP won't *help* you much with this kind of site. If you have *other* functionality in site that WP is actually good at, then it might be a possibility (since you will be implementing much of it yourself in any case).

If this is your site's main/only function you are likely better off considering alternatives first.

Comment: Thanks for the solid answer. I was looking at $wpdb() but I had no idea everything is cached. That def. ends that idea as my site already has timeout issues by trying to query too much. My reasoning for switching from a custom build to WP is because I am tired of building out all the plugins and doing all the things that come naturally to WP. E.g. An API for MailChimp v. clicking install.

Comment: As per conclusions this doesn't exclude making use of WP. If you are already building a custom implementation anyway, pulling it into WP to get benefit from _other_ things it offers can be a pretty valid route.

Answer (score -1):

Some time ago i would think that this is a valid thing you can ask from wp.

But now i think it is not.

I would choose Laravel for example over wp for what you seek. WP is NOT a full framework for line of bussiness apps.

Off course you can do what you need with WP but in the end you would wish you used something like laravel....

If i was to give an answer i would say that you have either to use core WP with custom post types and taxonomies to build your app or you could use your own custom tables.

Also a third option could be to utilize both and mix custom post types with custom tables....

Have in mind that you dont have an ORM at your disposal with wp...

Comment: It is rare to see an answer that is even worse then a bad question. Laravel might be better for him, but maybe he can't change things now after investing two years of development time and that is why he needs a wp solution? It doesn't really help him or almost anyone else to suggest that he should do his website in assembler.

Comment: Laravel is an assembler to those who think WP is a full framework for development of database intensive apps.

Comment: OP is going to thank himself if he even invests in going away from WP for the use he needs.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad answer per se, but I am looking for something to smooth over the front-end, not the back-end. I already built a custom back-end, and now I am looking to make things like A/B testing, newsletter sign ups, SEO, etc. easier.

Comment: @fwho but these are not db intensive operations. In these areas WP can perform exceptionally...Be more specific on what areas exactly you need help. Perhaps you could utilize wp-api http://v2.wp-api.org/ and get your data from backend to frontend..